# Capistrano current application path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

While deploying with Capistrano 3 I need to get the current local application path from a task, does Capistrano provides any static variable containing this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved using the current working directory `Dir.pwd`

Comment: is it possible for you to provide an example? I am on a mac and can not run pwd

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue where I was downloading a remote file with Capistrano and wanted to place it relative to the task file on my development machine. My rake task looked something like this:

```rb
# lib/capistrano/tasks/awesome_tasks.rake

namespace :awesome_tasks do

  task :do_something_awesome do

    # Set path to local folder containing the task
    path = Pathname.new(File.join(__dir__)) # => "parent_folders/app_root/lib/capistrano/tasks"

    # Do something with path...
  end

end
```

If you need the path to your application's root directory, you could do something like this:

```rb
# lib/capistrano/tasks/awesome_tasks.rake

namespace :awesome_tasks do

  task :do_something_awesome do

    # Set path to the root of the application.
    # Use #realpath to exclude the extra dots (optional)
    path = Pathname.new(File.join(__dir__, '../../..')).realpath # => "parent_folders/app_root"

    # Do something with path...
  end

end
```